# SQL Server import CSV (with line breaks and double quotations in cells)

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a CSV file which contains rows like:

```
"header1", "header2"
"header
    with many lines", """header with quotations in it"""
```

Which should appear in excel as:

```
header1,                  header2
header                    "header with quotations in it"
    with many lines
```

I want to import this into a SQL Server Database and preserve all characters and new lines as they would appear in Excel.
Will the bulk insert function support this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the best I can give you right now is a partial answer.  Your only hope on the BULK INSERT command would be a format file.  I'm not sure if that will work as I haven't used one before.

If you use SSIS you can set the Text Qualifier as " and that will fix your multiple line issues but still won't work with the quotations.  You might be able to apply a pre-processor to change the double "s to something else, then change them back once imported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving this CSV as Excel file and then using [SQL Server Import and Export wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) ? If that doesn’t work I’d try creating a simple .NET app that will parse the CSV file and import data into database.